# c++ ~ shared object -> get host application offsets

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, bsd

Im writing a shared library for a FreeBSD application.
This library gets loaded by LD_PRELOAD.

This application has multiple compile-versions, so some function offsets might change and my library wont work there.

Now i want to read the offsets at loading the library.
The offsets are changing, so i think my only way is to read the offsets of specific function names.

The offsets are simply the offsets of functions or labels.

Now the problem - how to do it?

### Example

In the first version, i call the main version like that:

```
int(*main)(int argc, char *argv[])=(int(*)(int,char*[]))0x081F3XXX;
```

but in the second, the offset has changed:

```
int(*main)(int argc, char *argv[])=(int(*)(int,char*[]))0x08233XXX;
```

Programmers (me) are lazy and don't want to compile their libs for every version.. I want to create a lib, that is for every version!

I simply need the offsets of the functions *via function name*, the rest is no problem..

Thats how i call the library:

```
LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/library.so" ./executable
```

or

```
env LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/library.so" ./executable
```

### Edit with test code

Here my testcode regarding to the comments:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test() {
    printf("Test done.\n");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("Program started\n");
    test();
}
```

lib.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_load(void);


void my_load(void) {
    printf("Library loaded\n");
    printf("test - offset: 0x%x\n",dlsym(NULL,"test"));
}
```

test.sh

```
g++ main.cpp -o program
g++ -shared lib.cpp -o lib.so
env LD_PRELOAD="lib.so" ./program
```

-> Result:

```
Library loaded
test - offset: 0x0
Program started
Test done.
```

Does not seem as would it work :s

## Edit 15:45

```
printf("test - offset: 0x%x\n",dlsym(dlopen("/home/test/test_proc/program",RTLD_GLOBAL),"test"));
```

This also does not work.. Maybe dlsym is the wrong way?

Comment: I'd say `void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol);`

Comment: dlsym reads the library and not the binary, doesnt it?

Comment: library is usually == binary, but if you mean executable, it can handle that as well.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds nice. Then i simply need the handle of the executable. Can the library read it anywhere? (i'm sure it can, but i simply dont know it).

Comment: It seems that dlopen needs the filepath.. Loop up, i edited the post so you can see how i call the process. The library does not know the filepath (because it can change).

Comment: "simply need the handle of the executable". It is spelled `NULL`. You may have to link your executable with `-rdynamic` if the symbol resides in the executable itself. No need to do so if it's in a preloaded library.

Comment: Thank you. I tested a little bit but i dont get to a working solution.. Look at the code i edited.

Comment: You forgot to link the executable with -rdynamic. The first version of the lib should wirk then.

Comment: Oh, and if you are doing C++, you need `extern "C"` for functions you want to `dlsym`, because of the name mangling.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do this in order to achieve something. What would that be?

Comment: I have written a library that detours functions in the executable. But the exec has different versions and i have to compile my lib for every version of it. And i want to create ONE library for ALL versions, even future versions.

Comment: Okay my test program is running. But the executable that i want to use is not linked with "-rdynamic". Any ideas?

Comment: @Mijago: relink it.  :)  Failing that, maybe you can do something with LibELF (https://wiki.freebsd.org/LibElf).

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your program on Mac OS X using Clang, and found a solution.  First, the boring parts:

To make it compile cleanly I had to change your `%x` format specifier to `%p` for the pointer.

Then, on Mac OS X I had to pass `RTLD_MAIN_ONLY` as the first argument to `dlsym()`.  I guess this is platform-dependent; on Linux it does seem to be NULL as you have.

Now, the meat of the fix!

You're searching with `dlsym()` for a symbol called `test`.  But there is no such symbol in your application.  Why?  Because you're using C++, and C++ does "name mangling."  You could use any number of tools to figure out the mangled name and try to load that with `dlsym()`, but it could change with different compilers.  So instead, just inhibit name mangling by enclosing your `test()` function in `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {
void test() {
    printf("Test done.\n");
}
}
```

This fixed it for me:

```
$ DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=lib.so ./program 
Library loaded
test - offset: 0x1027d1eb0
Program started
Test done.
```

Comment: The problem is, that the "program" is not mine, so I can not add the Extern "c" clause .. unfortunately.. And i tested your changes, it does not work for me :(

Comment: Well then use `nm` to dump the symbol table from your program and find the mangled form of the `test()` symbol and hope it doesn't change on your target platforms.